# How do I remove the \\?\ prefix from a canonical Windows path?

Tags: windows, rust

On Windows, `Path::canonicalize()` returns the path in the format:

```
\\\\?\\C:\\projects\\3rdparty\\rust...
```

This is because it is the correct canonical path, and allows 'long' paths on Windows (see [Why does my canonicalized path get prefixed with \\?\](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41233684/why-does-my-canonicalized-path-get-prefixed-with)).

However, this is not a user-friendly path, and people do not understand it.

For **display and logging purposes** how can I easily remove this prefix in a generic platform independent way?

`Path::components` will return a component `\\?\C:` as the first component...

Should I convert this to a `&str` and use a regex? Is there some other more ergonomic method for removing the prefix, e.g. some type with a `Display` implementation that automatically does the right thing?

My requirements specifically are:

- Correctly displays `X:\\...` for a canonical path on Windows.
- Doesn't screw up non-Windows platforms (e.g. strip or change path components)

Example:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

fn simple_path<P: AsRef<Path>>(p: P) -> String {
    String::from(p.as_ref().to_str().unwrap()) // <-- ?? What to do here?
}

pub fn main() {
    let path = PathBuf::from("C:\temp").canonicalize().unwrap();
    let display_path = simple_path(path);
    println!("Output: {}", display_path);
}
```

Comment: What should happen for `\\?\UNC\server\share`, and `\\?\cat_pics` ?

Comment: *Useless* is a tad strong, but I agree that it would certainly be overkill to use a regex here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The straightforward answer is to do platform-specific string munging:

```
use std::path::{Path, PathBuf};

#[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
fn adjust_canonicalization<P: AsRef<Path>>(p: P) -> String {
    p.as_ref().display().to_string()
}

#[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
fn adjust_canonicalization<P: AsRef<Path>>(p: P) -> String {
    const VERBATIM_PREFIX: &str = r#"\\?\"#;
    let p = p.as_ref().display().to_string();
    if p.starts_with(VERBATIM_PREFIX) {
        p[VERBATIM_PREFIX.len()..].to_string()
    } else {
        p
    }
}

pub fn main() {
    let path = PathBuf::from(r#"C:\Windows\System32"#)
        .canonicalize()
        .unwrap();
    let display_path = adjust_canonicalization(path);
    println!("Output: {}", display_path);
}
```

---

For the record, I don't agree that your premise is a good idea. Windows Explorer handles these verbatim paths just fine, and I think users are capable of handling it as well.

> For [...] logging purposes

This sounds like a terrible idea. If you are logging something, you want to know the *exact* path, not some potentially incorrect path.

Comment: I've received specific feedback on an internal cli tool that  paths rendered as `\\?\c:` were confusing and didn't work when copy pasted into notepad++.. What else can I realistically offer as a solution?

Comment: Sounds like this should get fixed in notepad++ rather than broken every where else, is there an issue opened about this on their tracker?

Comment: Funny enough, Notepad++ does support these ;)

Comment: @hellow It really doesn't. Try copy and pasting it into the File -> Open dialog in the 'File name' text box. It even auto-completes as you type if you type it out by hand, but it still won't open the file.

Comment: Notead++ v7.5.6 (64-bit). What's your version?

Comment: @hellow 7.5.4 (32-bit). It doesn't matter though; ultimately, if my application 'doesnt work' because of a bug in another application, it's still my problem to solve. I can't just be like 'oh, I'll just lodge a bug with application XXX because that's a bug', don't worry about it. Showing that prefix supposes that *every other application and user* will correctly handle it and know to copy and paste only the relevant part of it, which is demonstrably false. /shrug

Answer (score 12):

Use [the `dunce` crate](https://lib.rs/crates/dunce):

```
let compatible_path = dunce::canonicalize(&any_path);
```

Just stripping `\\?\` may give wrong/invalid paths. The dunce crate checks whether the UNC path is compatible and converts the path accurately whenever possible. It passes through all other paths. It compiles to plain `fs::canonicalize()` on non-Windows.

Comment: *converts the path accurately whenever possible* — so it doesn't always remove the `\\?`? Sounds like OPs users will still be angry.

Comment: @Shepmaster Are you saying it's a flaw that it doesn't do the *impossible* conversion?

Comment: Not at all; just that OP / OPs users want something impossible and will thus always be disappointed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a version that [reconstructs the path from the components](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/40159).

It helps with `std::fs::canonicalize` on Windows, but a naive `Path::new(r"\\?\C:\projects\3rdparty\rust")` at [play.rust-lang.org](https://play.rust-lang.org/) will produce a single-component `Path`.

```
use std::path::{Component, Path, PathBuf, Prefix};

// Should remove the “\\?” prefix from the canonical path
// in order to avoid CMD bailing with “UNC paths are not supported”.
let head = path.components().next().ok_or("empty path?")?;
let diskˢ;
let head = if let Component::Prefix(prefix) = head {
    if let Prefix::VerbatimDisk(disk) = prefix.kind() {
        diskˢ = format!("{}:", disk as char);
        Path::new(&diskˢ).components().next().ok_or("empty path?")?
    } else {
        head
    }
} else {
    head
};
println!("{:?}", head);
let path = std::iter::once(head)
    .chain(path.components().skip(1))
    .collect::<PathBuf>();
```

Answer (score -1):

You can implement a `StripCanonicalization` trait for PathBuf, which helps you keep a chainable calling.

```rust
pub trait StripCanonicalization where Self: AsRef<Path> {
    #[cfg(not(target_os = "windows"))]
    fn strip_canonicalization(&self) -> PathBuf {
        self.as_ref().to_path_buf()
    }

    #[cfg(target_os = "windows")]
    fn strip_canonicalization(&self) -> PathBuf {
        const VERBATIM_PREFIX: &str = r#"\\?\"#;
        let p = self.as_ref().display().to_string();
        if p.starts_with(VERBATIM_PREFIX) {
            PathBuf::from(&p[VERBATIM_PREFIX.len()..])
        } else {
            self.as_ref().to_path_buf()
        }
    }
}

impl StripCanonicalization for PathBuf {}
```

Calling like

```rust
let p = Path::new(s).canonicalize()?;
let p = p.strip_canonicalization();
```

Comment: This code is incorrect for non-utf8 filenames